# converting vmdk to vhdx then replace the file

Tags: powershell, converters, command-prompt, vmware, powershell-3.0

My problem is im converting vmdk to vhdx using powershell command
these is my scenario:
single.vmdk - This is the file to be converted as try.vhdx
try.vhdx- is existing in my desktop

so when i run my command the single.vmdk to try.vhdx  and it automatically replace the file not creating try(2).vmdk

i hope you can help me

this is the command i've been using:

ConvertTo-MvmcVirtualHardDisk -SourceLiteralPath "E:\single.vmdk" -VhdType DynamicHardDisk -VhdF
ormat Vhdx -Destination C:\Users\dmsadmin\Desktop\try.vhdx

Comment: Check if the file already exists and either delete or rename it.

Comment: i want it automatically deleted or rename using powershell it is possible?

Comment: Sure it's possible. You just need to implement it.

Comment: do you have suggestion on my code?

Comment: See my first comment.